# Silverlight control updates binded property when it should not

Tags: silverlight, binding, datagrid, silverlight-4.0, updatesourcetrigger

I have a custom control in datagrid `DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate`:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}">
   <DataGrid.Columns>                                   
      <data:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Column1" >
         <data:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
               <sdk:Label Content="{Binding Path=Description}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
         </data:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
         <data:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
               <common:MyControl SelectedObject="{Binding Path=SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
         </data:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
      </data:DataGridTemplateColumn>                                    
   </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Inside of control I have exactly one place where I update `SelectedObject` dependency property:

```
BindingExpression expressionObject = GetBindingExpression(SelectedObjectProperty);
if (expressionObject != null)
{
    expressionObject.UpdateSource();
}
```

This code is called on the `LostFocus` event.

**Problem is:** while `UpdateSource` method is called only once (checked with debugger) `SelectedItem` gets updated value(same) twice! I'm currently in loss since it's not supposed to be this way. Am I missing something?

**Edit:** I'm not using any MVVM framework. VS2012 debug callstack shows that first update is initiated by UpdateSource() call, but second just comes out of nowhere.

Comment: Are you using a MVVM framework? What result do you expect? Only one time in the getter? What valued do you have? 2 times the same value?

Comment: I don't use MVVM framework, and I expect to get value as many times as I call UpdateSource() in Control. In this case I call UpdateSource() once and I expect to get my value one time. But I get same value twice.

Comment: You Should Use Obsrvable Collection instadOf List